# Match number not ending with 0

Tags: regex

I'm matching whole and fractional numbers with the following pattern:

> (0|[1-9][0-9]*)(.[0-9]+)?

It matches for example the numbers:

```
0
1
12
12.1
12.12
```

But it also matches:

```
0.0
0.00
1.00
1.10
```

My question is how to modify the pattern above to disallow the match of numbers with ending zero after the decimal point.

Comment: which language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern `(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(.[0-9]+)?` matches all examples because the second part `(.[0-9]+)?` does not take into account that the last match should be 1-9. Note that you have to escape the dot `\.` to match it literally.

You could update the second part of your pattern to match 0+ times `[0-9]*` and make sure that the match ends with `[1-9]`:

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.[0-9]*[1-9])?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WEqp9e/1)

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(0|[1-9][0-9]*)` Capture group, match either 0 or 1 followed by 0+ times 0-9
- `(` Optional capturing group to match

  - `\.[0-9]*[1-9]` Match `.`, then 0+ times 0-9 followed by 1-9
- `)?`  Close group
- `$` End of string

If you are for example not referring to the capturing groups for further processing you might make them non capturing `(?:` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! After a little bit of research i realized that my problem can be solved with the use of a negative lookbehind: (0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.[0-9]+(?<!0))?

But your solutions is much easier to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(.(?:[0-9]+[1-9]|[1-9]))?$
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/ZtRg49/5

This will not match at all the following elements:

```
0.0
0.00
1.00
1.10
```

If you want to allow partial matches (not take into account the ending `0`), you can use:

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(.(?:[0-9]+[1-9]|[1-9]))?
```

demo https://regex101.com/r/ZtRg49/4/

**Explanations:**

- I have added the constraint that after the `.` there is one digit `[1-9]` or several digits that can contain `0` followed by a non zero digit `[1-9]`.
- By removing the ending anchor `$` you enable partial matches

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to this Problem:

```
^\d+$|[0-9.]*?[1-9]$
```

---

Requirements to be fulfilled:

- Match whole numbers
- Match floating point numbers not ending on `0`